# How do I specify the constraints in PuLP Python for multiplying two variables?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to model the following Integer Programming model using Python PuLP

[image]

I have written the following code :

```
from pulp import *

#knapsack problem

def knapsolve(item):

    prob = LpProblem('BinPacking', LpMinimize)

    ys = [LpVariable("y{0}".format(i+1), cat="Binary") for i in range(item.bins)]

    xs = [LpVariable("x{0}{1}".format(i+1, j+1), cat="Binary")
          for i in range(item.items) for j in range(item.bins)]

    #minimize objective
    nbins = sum(ys)
    prob += nbins

    print(nbins)

    #constraints

    t = nbins >= 1
    print(t)
    prob += t

    for i in range(item.items):
        con1 = sum(xs[(i + j*item.bins)]* ys[j] for j in range(item.bins))
        t = con1 == 1
        prob += t
        print(t)

    status = prob.solve()

    print(LpStatus[status])
    print("Objective value:", value(prob.objective))
    print ('\nThe values of the variables : \n')

    for v in prob.variables():
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

    return

class Probelm:
    #bins, binweight, items, weight, itemheight, binheight

    bins = 5
    items = 5

    binweight = [2,3,2,5,3]
    itemweight = [1,2,2,1,3]

    itemheight = [2,1,4,5,3]
    binheight = [4,9,10,8,10]


item = Problem()

knapsolve(item)
```

At runtime this provides the error :

```
y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5
y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 >= 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\BinPacking6.py", line 58, in <module>
    knapsolve(item)
  File "C:\Python34\BinPacking6.py", line 27, in knapsolve
    con1 = sum(xs[(i + j*item.bins)]* ys[j] for j in range(item.bins))
  File "C:\Python34\BinPacking6.py", line 27, in <genexpr>
    con1 = sum(xs[(i + j*item.bins)]* ys[j] for j in range(item.bins))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.6.1-py3.4.egg\pulp\pulp.py", line 209, in __mul__
    return LpAffineExpression(self) * other
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.6.1-py3.4.egg\pulp\pulp.py", line 786, in __mul__
    return self * LpAffineExpression(other)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.6.1-py3.4.egg\pulp\pulp.py", line 774, in __mul__
    raise TypeError("Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied")
TypeError: Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied
```

As far as I can identify, the problem lies in `con1 = sum(xs[(i + j*item.bins)]* ys[j] for j in range(item.bins))`. How do I specify the constraints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message from PuLP is correct. You are trying to pass a non-linear construct (multiplication of two variables) to PuLP while PuLP is designed for linear models only. Fortunately, the simple bin-packing model you want to solve can be formulated as a linear MIP model, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). Before starting typing some Python code it often helps me to first write down the mathematical model more precise than what you posted (which is too general).

Comment: I'm trying to do a two dimensional bin packing, the Wikipedia entry corresponds to a one dimensional one

Comment: Sorry, I assumed this was a step you could make. Just add another constraint just like `sum(j,  a(i)*x(i,j)) <= V`.

Comment: <=V or <=V subscript y[i] ?

Comment: Yes, times `y` is probably a good idea (although not needed as y=0=>x=0 is already taken care of by the other capacity constraint; so it is possible to drop in the second).

Comment: I actually tried the following code `for k in range(item.bins):
        x = xs[k*item.bins : (k+1)*item.bins]
        con1 = sum([x1*w for x1, w in zip(x, item.itemweight)])
        t = con1 <= item.binweight[k] * ys[k]
        prob += t` and `for k in range(item.bins):
        x = xs[k*item.bins : (k+1)*item.bins]
        con1 = sum([x1*w for x1, w in zip(x, item.itemheight)])
        t = con1 <= item.binheight[k] * ys[k]
        prob += t` to specify the height and weight constraints and it is producing incorrect results

Comment: You have more chance to get help to fix your Python program if you post a complete, and reproducible program. Having said that, it is a good idea to use WriteLP to debug the Pulp model.